# What is the meaning of this error in gstreamer -plugin intstallation?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, configure

I have built `gstreamer & gst-base plug-in` from source but while configuring 
`gst-plugins-good-0.10.30`, I am getting error like this

```
checking for struct ip_mreqn... yes
checking for GLIB... configure: 
configure: error: This package requires GLib >= 2.20 to compile.
```

What is the meaning of this error and how can I install `gst-plugins-good-0.10.30`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can mean one of the following things:
1. You don't have `Glib` development package (`-devel`) installed i.e. header files & pkg-config (.pc) file for `Glib`. You can check this using `dpkg` or `yum` or other commands based on your Linux distro. 
2. You have `Glib` development package installed but the version is not `2.20` or higher. To check the version see the output of `pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0`
3. You have `Glib` development package installed but the `pkg-config` is not able to find it. You will have to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable in this case.
For the packages needed in case of gstreamer source, there is a `REQUIREMENTS`file with the list of required packages. Also, `configure` will throw missing package which are needed. You will need to install from source or from the repo configure for your distro.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This means you need GLib 2.20 or later, obviously. On a Linux platform, first check whether a recent enough GLib is available in your package manager and install it if it is; it's probably called `libglib` or similar. Don't forget to also install the `-devel` (Debian, Ubuntu) or `-dev` (Red Hat, SuSE, CentOS, Fedora) package that comes with it; that package contains stuff you need to compile programs against GLib.

If the GLib in your system is too old, consider upgrading your Linux, or install GLib from source.